# In app billing giving me errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been playing around with both dungeons sample in app billing code with google and blundell's tutorial in app billing code. Both of these projects are basically out of the box besides changing the public key, renaming the application, and uploading it to google which I have already done. The two apps were working fine just recently (around 3 days ago). Now i'm getting this error both in the LogCat and the Device.

Device:

```
Error retrieving information from server. [DF-DFERH-01]
```

LogCat:

```
10-13 02:26:12.449: E/Volley(916): [90] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/purchaseStatus
10-13 02:26:12.457: W/Finsky(916): [1] CheckoutPurchase.onErrorResponse: DisplayErrorMessage[Error retrieving information from server. [DF-DFERH-01]]
10-13 02:26:12.457: E/Finsky(916): [1] CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=UNKNOWN, code=-1, message=Error retrieving information from server. [DF-DFERH-01]
```

Comment: I contacted Android Support, i'll post the solution when they find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after contacting Android support here is the answer I got. I have yet to verify if unstatic testing works. I will let you all know.

> Comment #190 on issue 35564 by theother...@gmail.com: error
>   (DF-DFERH-01) http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35564
>
> Hi everyone. So I experienced the same problem testing the static
>   responses these last few days. I decided to ignore them and go ahead
>   and test real products (I was able to do this since my app already had
>   live versions published, without In-app purchases of course). Testing
>   real products did work however.
>
> After reading the IAP Testing guide
>   (http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static)
>   I came across a quote:
>
> "Note: Making in-app billing requests with the reserved product IDs
>   overrides the usual Google Play production system. When you send an
>   in-app billing request for a reserved product ID, the quality of
>   service will not be comparable to the production environment."
>
> So it seems something is indeed wrong with the static response
>   service, but this does not reflect the conditions of the actual Play
>   Store. I can vouch for this because my now updated and live App has
>   IAP working without problems. So if you're having this problem, test
>   real products if you can; it will probably work for you.